# How to disable 'created with inkscape' comment in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, inkscape

I am looking for a way to prevent Inkscape from adding the following comment to all files (even "optimized SVG" contains this comment).

```svg
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
```

In edit > preferences > Input/Output I was not able to find any settings. The obligatory Google search didn't wash up anything. Is there a template where I can edit the export? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The node.js module [SVGO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo) or the derived [Inkscape plugin](https://github.com/konsumer/inkscape-svgo) can do that for you. Mind you, it will change the file in a lot of other ways if you are not carefull. For only removing comments, disable **all** plugins but `removeComments`.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

The solution is to create a new (default) template for Inkscape, which does not contain the comment:

1. Open Inkscape
2. Save default document as `default.svg` in `~/.config/inkscape/templates`
3. Close Inkscape
4. Open `~/.config/inkscape/templates/default.svg` with a text editor and remove comment and save file.
5. Open Inkscape. The default document is now being loaded from `~/.config/inkscape/templates/default.svg` - saving work, which based on the template, will not contain the comment.

Answer (score 0):

That comment is part of the template.

You can either:

- create a custom template where you have edited the comment out (with a text editor) or
- save as 'optimized SVG' and check the option to remove comments from the file

(see also: https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/678817)